# How to show in terminal the time for each Mocha test, using Mongoose code

Tags: windows, mongoose, mocha.js

I started to learn Mocha testing from a tutorial. In this tutorial I see the total time for all tests, but in my opinion it is important to see the time for each test.

[image]

I put this screenshot so you can see how I get the tests ouput right now.

I ran all the code on ***windows OS***.

"mocha": "^9.0.3",

"mongoose": "^5.13.5"

The folders structure:

```
src -> users.js
test -> test_helper.js
     -> create_test.js
     -> read_test.js
```

user.js file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

test_helper.js file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/users_test", {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
});
mongoose.connection
  .once("open", () => {
    console.log("Mongoose Connected!");
  })
  .on("error", (error) => {
    console.warn("Warning", error);
  });

beforeEach((done) => {
  const { users } = mongoose.connection.collections;
  users.drop(() => {
    // Ready to run next tests
    done();
  });
});
```

create_test.js file:

```
const assert = require("assert");
const User = require("../src/user");

describe("Creating records", () => {
  it("saves a user", (done) => {
    const user = new User({ name: "Joe" });

    user
      .save()
      .then(() => {     
        assert(!user.isNew);
        done();
      })
      .catch(done);
  });
});
```

read_test.js file:

```
const assert = require("assert");
const User = require("../src/user");

describe("Reading users out of the database", () => {
  let joe, maria, alex, zach;

  beforeEach((done) => {
    joe = new User({ name: "Joe" });
    alex = new User({ name: "Alex" });
    maria = new User({ name: "Maria" });
    zach = new User({ name: "Zach" });

    Promise.all([joe.save(), alex.save(), maria.save(), zach.save()]).then(() =>
      done()
    );
  });

  it("finds all users with a name of joe", (done) => {
    User.find({ name: "Joe" }).then((users) => {
      assert(users[0]._id.toString() === joe._id.toString());
      done();
    });
  });

  it("find a user with a particular id", (done) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: joe._id }).then((user) => {
      // assert(user.name === "Joe");
      assert(user._id.toString() === joe._id.toString());
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

In package.json I tried different commands, but with the same output:

With this inside scripts:

```
 "start:test": "mocha test/ --recursive --exit",
 "test": "nodemon --exec \"npm run start:test\"",
```

or this:

```
"test": "nodemon --watch . --exec \"mocha || true\""
```

I got the same ouput in terminat, with total time for all tests.

You can just copy all code that I put here, put it locally on your computer and test it. Of course you have to have a MongoDB database running in a terminal, to run all of this code.

So, please someone tell me, how can I ouput in terminal the time for each test?

Answer (score 1):

I asked on [Mocha github](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/4712) about this situation and a member helped me to understand that there are 2 ways to show the time:

**1.  seting the --slow option to zero: --slow 0**

```
"scripts": {
      "start:test": "mocha  test/ --slow 0 --recursive --exit",
      "test": "nodemon --exec \"npm run start:test\""
  },
```

[image]

**2. using a reporter list: --reporter list**

```
"scripts": {
      "start:test": "mocha  test/ --reporter list --recursive --exit",
      "test": "nodemon --exec \"npm run start:test\""
  }
```

[image]

I searched a lot for at least one option, but now I found 2 :)).

I hope this will help others to save their time.